# How to find tables having foreign key to a table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, key

I plan to delete data from a table, I would like to know how many and which tables have a foreign key reference to this particular table in Oracle. As I will have to set the foreign keys to null. I would like to know list of all tables which have a FK to this particular table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle all foreign key references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171373/oracle-all-foreign-key-references)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find which tables reference a given table in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT d.table_name,

       d.constraint_name "Primary Constraint Name",

       b.constraint_name "Referenced Constraint Name"

FROM user_constraints d,

     (SELECT c.constraint_name,

             c.r_constraint_name,

             c.table_name

      FROM user_constraints c 

      WHERE table_name='EMPLOYEES' --your table name instead of EMPLOYEES

      AND constraint_type='R') b

WHERE d.constraint_name=b.r_constraint_name
```

Comment: I believe that should be, `"Referencing Constraint Name"`, as that is the name of the constraint that references the primary constraint, not the other way around.

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT
  FK.OWNER||'.'||FK.TABLE_NAME AS CHILD_TABLE,
  SRC.OWNER||'.'||SRC.TABLE_NAME AS PARENT_TABLE,
  FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS FK_CONSTRAINT,
  SRC.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS REFERENCED_CONSTRAINT
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS FK
JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS SRC ON FK.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = SRC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
  FK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
  AND SRC.OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
  AND SRC.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

I have a situation where the table I'm interested in isn't owned by the schema I was connecting as. So I needed to modify the query in the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752111/1394393) to use `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` instead of `USER_CONSTRAINTS`. In the process, I made a mistake, and I found the accepted answer to be very difficult to read so that I could fix it. (The lack of explanation didn't help.) As a result, I ended up coming up with my own query. It's basically the same, but I think it's a bit easier to grok.

`FK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'` filters down `FK` to a set of foreign key constraints, and the join pairs these foreign keys up with their "Referenced constraint". (The referenced constraint is usually the primary key of the "parent" table.) Finally, we filter down to the parent table we're interested in using `SRC.OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA' AND SRC.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'`.

Naturally, you can switch this to use `USER_CONSTRAINTS` if you wish; just remove the `SRC.OWNER` check and the `OWNER` prefixes in the `SELECT`.

Comment: FK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' is not required for this

Comment: @abhihello123 Probably not strictly, as `FK.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME` is probably `NULL` for rows with other types. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 6):

Below query will give all the foreign key constraints defined on TABLE_NAME:

```
select baseTable.* from all_constraints baseTable , all_constraints referentedTable 
    where baseTable.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = referentedTable.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    and baseTable.constraint_type = 'R'
    and referentedTable.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: Why `baseTable.constraint_type = 'R'`?

Comment: 'R' stands for Referential integrity and we want to check only foreign key constraint here. So baseTable.constraint_type = 'R' should be used. constraint_type can also take other possible values which you can check here -> 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022

Comment: This query will pick up on all tables of that name regardless of schema. If multiple tables in different schemas have the same name, it will pick all of them up. What's even worse is that your choice of `SELECT`ed columns makes it impossible to tell *which* table is being referenced when it does find multiple ones.

Comment: @jpmc26 : Well in that case you can just add a filter clause on schema, that's it. One has to tailor queries according to their custom needs, simple.

Comment: @nanosoft Except that if you added the filter, it would 1. behave as one would actually expect, and 2. be identical to existing answers. "You can fix it yourself," is not a defense for it behaving in unhelpful ways.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I didn't use my words as defense. It was genuine and as this argument is going non-productive to other viewers as a responsible member now I abstain to act on it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood what Walker asked, but what I understood is : How to find tables that have a foreign key reference to a particular table (ex : EMPLOYEES).

If I try Kupa's answer :

```
select d.table_name,
       d.constraint_name "Primary Constraint Name",
       b.constraint_name "Referenced Constraint Name"

from user_constraints d,

     (select c.constraint_name,
             c.r_constraint_name,
             c.table_name
      from user_constraints c 
      where table_name='EMPLOYEES' --your table name instead of EMPLOYEES
      and constraint_type='R') b

where d.constraint_name=b.r_constraint_name
```

I get the tables on which EMPLOYEES have a foreign key reference to.

EMPLOYEES.foreign_key => TABLES.primary_key

---

See below the updated sql to retrieve the tables that have a foreign key reference to EMPLOYEES.

TABLES.foreign_key => EMPLOYEES.primary_key

```
select b.table_name "Table Name",
   b.constraint_name "Constraint Name",
   d.table_name "Referenced Table Name",
   d.constraint_name "Referenced Constraint Name"

from user_constraints d,

 (select c.constraint_name,
         c.r_constraint_name,
         c.table_name
  from user_constraints c
  where constraint_type='R') b

where d.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' --your table name instead of EMPLOYEES
and b.r_constraint_name = d.constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also need the fields to be included:

```
select b.table_name      "Referencing Table", 
       b.CONSTRAINT_NAME "Referencing Constraint",
       (select wm_concat(column_name)
          from all_cons_columns
         where owner = b.owner
           and constraint_name = b.CONSTRAINT_NAME
       ) "Referencing Columns",
       a.CONSTRAINT_NAME         "Referenced Constraint",
       (select wm_concat(column_name)
          from all_cons_columns
         where owner = a.owner
           and constraint_name = a.CONSTRAINT_NAME
       ) "Referenced columns"
  from all_constraints a,
       all_constraints b
 where a.owner = b.r_owner
   and a.owner = '<<OWNER>>'
   and a.table_name = '<<TABLE_NAME>>'
   and a.constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and b.constraint_type = 'R'
   and b.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = a.constraint_name
```

Comment: wm_concat doesn't work in my version of Oracle. I replaced those 2 lines with: select listagg(column_name) within group (order by position) "columns"

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this step manually - you can just use a [cascading delete](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm).

Comment: You need to first *find* the table whose FK needs updated to permit cascase delete though

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       -- referenced pk
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND a.table_name = :TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME from ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OWNER= sys_context('userenv','current_schema') AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R';
```